# Is there a way to execute WebFilter for a specific urls in spring webflux

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a WebFilter which I would like to exclude for couple of urls.

I have used PathPattern which can be used to exclude 1 url but not more than that.

private final PathPattern pathPattern;

```
public MyFilter() {
    pathPattern = new PathPatternParser().parse("/url");
}
```

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

    if (pathPattern.matches(exchange.getRequest().getPath().pathWithinApplication())) {
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do it, below is one of the way

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class LogFilter implements WebFilter {

    List<PathPattern> pathPatternList;

    public LogFilter() {
        PathPattern pathPattern1 = new PathPatternParser()
                .parse("/admin");
        PathPattern pathPattern2 = new PathPatternParser().parse("/emp");
        pathPatternList = new ArrayList<>();
        pathPatternList.add(pathPattern1);
        pathPatternList.add(pathPattern2);

    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        RequestPath path = exchange.getRequest().getPath();
        if (pathPatternList.stream().anyMatch(pathPattern -> pathPattern.matches(path.pathWithinApplication()))) {
            log.info(path.toString() + " path excluded");
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }
        log.info("executing logic for " + path.toString() + " path");
        return chain.filter(exchange);

    }
}
```

For Url `/admin` and `/emp` it will exclude the logic for other urls it will execute the logic check below logs

```
2019-05-10 00:20:55.660  INFO 15837 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.l.reactiveapp.filter.LogFilter         : /admin path excluded
2019-05-10 00:20:55.661  INFO 15837 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.l.r.controller.AdminController         : get admin
2019-05-10 00:20:58.361  INFO 15837 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.l.reactiveapp.filter.LogFilter         : /emp path excluded
2019-05-10 00:20:58.362  INFO 15837 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.l.r.controller.EmployeeController      : get employee
2019-05-10 00:21:03.649  INFO 15837 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.l.reactiveapp.filter.LogFilter         : executing logic for /messages/10 path
2019-05-10 00:21:03.651  INFO 15837 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.l.r.controller.StoresController        : getting message details for id 10 enter code here
```

i hope this answers your question
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your WebFilter with decorator that restricts inner WebFilter invocation by provided ServerWebExchangeMatcher.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RestrictedWebFilterDecorator implements WebFilter {
    private final WebFilter inner;
    private final ServerWebExchangeMatcher restrictionMatcher;
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return restrictionMatcher.matches(exchange)
                .flatMap(result -> result.isMatch()
                        ? inner.filter(exchange, chain)
                        : chain.filter(exchange)
                );
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Bean
public WebFilter yourWebFilter() {
    return new RestrictedWebFilterDecorator(
            new YourWebFilter,
            new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(YOUR_EXCHANGE_MATCHER)
    );
}
```

Comment: I like that Lombok annotation you had, that would reduce more boilerplate for the injected code.